# "Response is committed, can't handle exception" Error When sending the same Rest API request twice

Tags: teiid, redhat-datavirt

I am using teiid Virtual Procedure to create a Rest API and expose my data. I have enabled result set caching using Cache Hints. When I send the same API request twice I get no data in the second attempt and teiid console logs the bellow exception. However when the caching is disabled or if I send the second request after waiting till the cache get invalidated (after ttl time) requests are executed properly and I get the relevant response. And another important observation that i made is that when the response size is limited to be less than some size (eg. using LIMIT clause to limit response size to 10 records), the requests are served properly with caching enabled. This happens only when I increase the records size after a particular size (in my case 15).

Can I know the reason behind this and any fixes or workarounds so I can continue to use result set caching without having this issue.

```
 05:04:52,909 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-20) UT005023: Exception handling request to /TestView_1/report/get_data: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: RESTEASY003770: Response is committed, can't handle exception
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:167)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:415)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invokePropagateNotFound(SynchronousDispatcher.java:240)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:225)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: already removed
    at org.teiid.common.buffer.FileStore.checkRemoved(FileStore.java:162)
    at org.teiid.common.buffer.FileStore.read(FileStore.java:156)
    at org.teiid.common.buffer.FileStore$1.nextBuffer(FileStore.java:223)
    at org.teiid.common.buffer.ExtensibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(ExtensibleBufferedInputStream.java:42)
    at org.teiid.common.buffer.ExtensibleBufferedInputStream.read(ExtensibleBufferedInputStream.java:54)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:100)
    at org.teiid.core.util.ReaderInputStream.read(ReaderInputStream.java:94)
    at org.teiid.core.util.ObjectConverterUtil.write(ObjectConverterUtil.java:106)
    at org.teiid.core.util.ObjectConverterUtil.write(ObjectConverterUtil.java:143)
    at org.teiid.core.util.ObjectConverterUtil.write(ObjectConverterUtil.java:139)
    at org.teiid.jboss.rest.TeiidRSProvider$1.write(TeiidRSProvider.java:72)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:32)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:17)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:131)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(ServerWriterInterceptorContext.java:60)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:120)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalSigningInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(DigitalSigningInterceptor.java:145)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:124)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPEncodingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(GZIPEncodingInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:124)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:98)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:466)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: When the resultset size is small the whole result is kept in memory, after a certain size it will be written to disk. The error seem to indicate that the saved cached some how got removed before the TTL. Can you see if the same error exists if you query without the REST API?

Comment: Did you mean try using odata or some other protocol to issue requests to the virtual procedure model.

Comment: I'm using only one server under the 'main server group'. Initially by default there were two other servers under the 'Other sever group' and I removed them from the configuration. Is that any possible link to this issue. And I have configured this server under 'ha' profile. can I know the additional benefits that I would gain if I used 'full-ha'

Comment: Try using Jdbc client to issue query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution for this. I tried Jdbc cliet as @ramesh mentioned. But the issue persist.
This issue persist for both XML and JSON format responses we retrieve from REST API. 
This only happens when the response size is larger than 4000 characters which is the default limit for teiid. I increased this limit from the System Properties using management console and re-start the teiid cluster.

```
property                     value    boot-time
org.teiid.maxStringLength    200000   true
```

This solved this Empty cache response issue.